# Bootstrap - I cannot center my five two columns inside of a ten column inside of a twelve column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot center my five two columns inside of a ten column inside of a twelve column. http://jsfiddle.net/p8znkgv2/. I have tried the following "solutions" without any luck:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-1"> </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-centered">
        <div class="col-sm-2">Coontent</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">Coontent</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">Coontent</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">Coontent</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">Coontent</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"> </div>
</div>
```

```
.col-centered{ margin: auto; float: none; }
```

- Make the container a table and each column a table cell item ( failed )
- Make the container (10 column) float none with an auto margin. ( failed on large displays )

So how can I center each two column inside the ten column with the ten column centered inside the twelve column?

Comment: looked at your jsfiddle.. are those columns supposed to be stacked that way ? !!

Comment: cant you use offset instead divs or are you going to have content in those 1 columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how can I center each two column inside the ten column with the ten column centered inside the twelve column?

By using `.col-sm-offset-*` class. Examples can be found here. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting. Here's a fiddle as well. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/m12cysv1/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/p8znkgv2/2/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-1">Coontent</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">Coontent</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">Coontent</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">Coontent</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">Coontent</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of problems with your structure.

One is you create child `div` elements with those grid classes e.g. `col-sm-*` without adding and element with `.row` class first.

Html should be:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-1"> </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-centered">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">Coontent</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">Coontent</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">Coontent</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">Coontent</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">Coontent</div>
                    </div>    
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

And regarding to center those 5 cols, since there's no specific class for 5 cols since it's a 12 grid system, add a custom style for those elements.

e.g.

```
.col-centered .row .col-sm-2 {
    width: 20%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8znkgv2/1/)

Comment: Because their nested, it doesn't necessarily have to add up to 12. Direct from Bootstrap. _"Nested rows should include a set of columns that add up to 12 or fewer (it is not required that you use all 12 available columns)."_ http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Comment: @ChrisYongchu Yep, I agree, it's not necessarily have to add up to 12 as long as it fits with what you desire